# Seeing non-friends status updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

If a friend has their status update privacy set to 'Friends of Friends', does that mean that everyone on *my* friends list sees all their status updates, regardless of whether I 'like' or comment on the status? If so, is there any way to change this so that my friends don't see all her status updates?

Answer (score 1):

Your friends will only see her status updates if

- They go on her profile
- Your like/comment story on one of her posts gets propagated to the ticker or news feed

Even if you were somehow able to change your privacy to fix this (which you cannot), seeing that the privacy range is "Friends of Friends" if "John" is friends with your friends and friends with her, some of your friends will still be able to see her updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your Profile so when your friends (or a customer group you can add specific people to if you want to limit it) don't see your friends list.
This won't stop them going to your friends page another way, but will limit them from linking to your site.

You can do this by:

1. Clicking on your project (Your photo/name at the top right)
2. Click on Friends
3. Click on the pencil icon on the right, then "Edit privacy"
4. Change "Friend List" to "Only me" or Customer if you want to pick a group.